# Conjugation and homology on projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, projective-geometry

Let $X = \mathrm{Proj}\ \mathbb{C}[T_0,\dots,T_n]/I$ be a projective variety (**Edit:** I am mainly interested in the case of a curve), where $I$ is generated by polynomials with **real** coefficients. Then conjugation acts on $X$ (by conjugating coefficients of polynomials).

> Question $(1)$: I am quite sure that conjugation is an automorphism of $X$ (automorphism of algebraic variety), is it right? **Edit:** This was answered by tjf below.

If it is an automorphism of $X$, then it also acts on the homology groups $H_k(X,\mathbb{Q})$ of $X$ by automorphisms. We can define in the obvious way *invariant* and *alternating* $k-$cycles: in the first case $\gamma = \overline{\gamma}$ and in the second case $\gamma = -\overline{\gamma}$. Not all $k-$cycles need to have one of this two forms, but we have that

$$ H_k(X,\mathbb{Q}) = H_k(X,\mathbb{Q})^+ \oplus H_k(X,\mathbb{Q})^-,$$

where $+$ and $-$ denote the fact of being invariant or alternating. The above is true because each $k-$cycle $\gamma$ can be decomposed uniquely as

$$ \gamma = \frac{\gamma + \overline{\gamma}}{2} + \frac{\gamma - \overline{\gamma}}{2},$$

a sum of an invariant and an alternating $k-$cycle.

> Question $(2)$: are $H_k(X,\mathbb{Q})^+$ and $H_k(X,\mathbb{Q})^-$ isomorphic, or do they at least have the same dimension? I think this is some form of orbit-stabilizer, but I cannot formulate it properly. **Edit:** As  Nicolas Hemelsoet points out, this is in general not true. So I would just like an answer for $X$ a curve and $k=1$.

Comment: There are some obvious restrictions, e.g many times $H_k$ can be odd dimensional. So I guess your question is when $H_k$ is even dimensional, and it should be possible (I'm not super sure) to construct explicitely some counter-example using Hodge theory. Would you be interested ?

Comment: Regarding Question (1), you must be careful. Conjugation is a scheme automorphism of $X$ but NOT an automorphism of algebraic variety. When the term 'algebraic variety' is used, there is an implicit base field $k$ over which this variety is defined; in this case it is $k=\mathbb{C}$. By definition, a morphism of algebraic varieties (over $k$) is a $k$-morphism. This is not the case for the complex conjugation.

Comment: @Nicolas Hemelsoet I have formulated a more general question than what I actually needed: I am just interested in the case where $X$ is a curve (Riemann surface) and $k=1$ (loops on $X$), so that $\mathrm{dim}_\mathbb{Q}(H_1(X,\mathbb{Q})) = 2g$, where $g$ is the genus of $X$. I do not know if I have enough background to understand counter-examples with Hodge theory, but if you have something for the special case I am interested in, I am all ears!

Comment: @tjf Thanks for the reminder, I had forgotten it! Still, I just need it to be a homeomorphism in order to induce an automorphism in homology, so all is well that ends well :)

Comment: @57Jimmy : my example was for surfaces. But I'm not so convinced it should be true for curves : for example I suspect that conjugation-invariant loops should be in $\Bbb RP^2$. If this is true, then there are bunch of smooth curves with empty real locus which would immediately give a counter-example.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Just to be sure: I meant complex curves, hence real surfaces (Riemann surfaces). And I can assume that the curve has real (even rational) solutions.

Comment: If your curve is smooth then its real locus is a collection or circles so has Euler characteristic zero; thus you can apply Lefschetz fixed point formula to conclude that the dimension of subspace of H_1 on which conjugation is identity is half of the total dimension of H_1.  If your curve is not smooth H_1 does not have to be even dimensional so the statement is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one proof.

**Lemma.** Let $X$ be a cell complex, $G$ a finite group and $G\times X\to X$ is an action. Then for every field $F$ of characteristic zero,
$$
H^*(X/G; F)\cong H^*(X;F)^{G},
$$
where the right hand-side is the ring of invariants under the $G$-action on $H^*(X)$.

This lemma is an application of the "transfer", you can find its proof for insatnce in Bredon's book "Compact Transformation Groups" or in [these](http://www.indiana.edu/~jfdavis/seminar/transformationgroupsb.pdf) freely available notes by Alan Edmonds. (Edmonds treats only the case $F={\mathbb Q}$ but the general case is no different.)

**Proposition.** Let $G={\mathbb Z}_2$ acting as complex conjugation on an irreducible smooth complex-projective curve $X$ defined over ${\mathbb R}$. (More generally, one can allow a singular irreducible curve $X$ such that none of its singular points is real.) Then the dimension of the $G$-invariant subspace in $H^1(X; {\mathbb Q})$ is half of the dimension of   $H^1(X; {\mathbb Q})$.

**Proof.** Let $Y:= X/G$. I first consider the case when $G$ has nonempty fixed-point set in $X$. Then $X$ (as a topological space) is obtained by gluing two copies  of $Y$ along a disjoint union of circles $F\subset Y$ (the projection of the fixed-point set of the action of $G$ on $X$). Then, since $\chi(F)=0$,
$$
\chi(X)=2\chi(Y). 
$$
Since $H^2(Y; {\mathbb Q})=0$, we obtain that 
$$\chi(X)= 2- dim H^1(X; {\mathbb Q})=  2- 2 dim H^1(Y; {\mathbb Q})$$ 
and, hence (by Lemma), 
$$ 
dim H^1(X; {\mathbb Q})= 2 dim H^1(Y; {\mathbb Q})= 2 dim H^1(X; {\mathbb Q})^G.
$$
If $G$ acts freely on $X$, the proof is essentially the same. Since the Euler characteristic is multiplicative under covering maps and 
taking into account that $Y=X/G$ is nonorientable and, hence, has $H^2(Y; {\mathbb Q})=0$, again obtain 
$$
2- dim H^1(X; {\mathbb Q})= \chi(X)= 2\chi(Y)= 2- 2 dim H^1(Y; {\mathbb Q}).
$$
Then, proceed as before. qed

If $X$ has odd number of singular points, then $dim H^1(X; {\mathbb Q})$ is odd and, hence, the proposition cannot be true. I leave it to somebody else to sort out the case of general complex-projective curves.

**Edit.** Here are answers to your questions. Almost all of this one learns in a graduate course in algebraic or differential topology (plus a complex analysis class).

1. First of all, this is a general fact of differential topology that if $G$ is a compact group acting smoothly on a manifold $M$ then the fixed-point set $Fix_M(G)$ of the action is a smooth submanifold (this was discussed several times at MSE, for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739644/is-the-fixed-point-set-of-an-action-a-submanifold)). If $M$ is compact then $Fix_M(G)$ is also compact. (The latter is actually a fact of general topology: a closed subset of a compact space is compact.) In the case when $M$ is a Riemann surface $X$ and $G$ is cyclic orientation-reversing (antiholomorphic) then by linearizing the action at its fixed-points you see that the generator of $g$ (in holomorphic coordinates near any fixed point) has the form $z\mapsto \bar{z}$. Then $Fix_M(G)$ is a 1-dimensional manifold. By the classification of 1-dimensional manifolds, every connected 1-dimensional manifold is either empty or is a circle. Every compact 1-dimensional manifold is a finite union of circles.
2. If $Fix_X(G)$ is nonempty and $X$ is connected (which is always the case if $X$ is an irreducible smooth complex projective curve) then $Y=X/G$ is a connected manifold with nonempty boundary (projection of the fixed point set of $G$). Hence, $H^2(Y; {\mathbb Q})=0$. You can see this, for instance, by observing that $Y$ is homotopy-equivalent to a bouquet of circles. (One can derive this for instance from the classification of compact surfaces with boundary.)
3. If $G$ acts freely then $Y=X/G$ is a connected manifold. (This is a general fact about properly discontinuous free group actions on manifolds: The quotient is always a manifold and the quotient map is a covering.) The fact that the image of a connected space under a continuous map is connected is a fact of general topology which one typically learns in a general topology class. In particular, $X/G$ cannot be a disjoint union of two homeomorphic copies of anything.
4. If $X$ is an orientable connected manifold and $X\to X/G$ is a quotient by a free properly discontinuous action which does not preserve orientation then $Y=X/G$ is a nonorientable connected manifold. (This was discussed many times at MSE, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177045/the-orientation-of-quotient-manifold), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196136/proving-that-the-quotient-manifold-is-orientable-if-and-only-if-the-group-action), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163502/m-gamma-is-orientable-iff-the-elements-of-gamma-are-orientation-preserving),....) In particular, $H^2(Y; {\mathbb Q})=0$.
5. Lastly, consider the complex manifold $M={\mathbb C}P^n$ and let $g: M\to M$ be the complex conjugation
   $$
   (z_0: z_1:...:z_n)\mapsto (\bar{z}_0: \bar{z}_1:...:\bar{z}_n). 
   $$
   Then for every complex line $L$ in $T_pM$ the map $dg_p: L\to dg_p(L)\subset T_pM$ is orientation-reversing. This is a fact of linear algebra. (Consider the lift of $g$ to ${\mathbb C}^{n+1}$.) In particular, if $X\subset M$ is a Riemann surface and $g(X)= X$, then $g: X\to X$ reverses orientation on $X$ (the orientation is induced by the complex structure of $X$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The smooth case is actually enough for me. I still have a couple of questions, being rather new in this field:

Comment: 1) Why is $F$ a disjoint union of circles? 2) Why in the second case don't we get a disjoint union of two copies of $Y$ with the same reasoning as in the first case? 3) Why is $H^2(Y,\mathbb{Q})=0$? 4) Why is $Y$ non-orientable in the second case?

Comment: P.S. concise answers are enough, I just need to know if they are standard facts of some sort that I can look up somewhere or if they are specific to this problem

Comment: @57Jimmy All this is very standard. For instance if you have a connected surface with nonempty boundary then it has zero 2nd cohomology; same for nonorientable connected surfaces. Complex conjugation reverses orientation, hence quotient by a free action given by complex conjugation will need nonorientable.

Comment: Thanks again a lot for your answer. Please allow me one last question: you say that in the case where $G$ acts freely, we still have $H_2(X/G,\mathbb{Q})=0$. This seems to be in contrast to a statement in the notes of Edmonds you have linked, just after Corollary 9.2: "If $G$ acts freely on a closed oriented $n$-manifold $M$, then $H_n(M, \mathbb{Z}) =  \mathbb{Z} = H_n(M/G, \mathbb{Z})$". What am I missing?

Comment: @57Jimmy: You are not missing anything, this is Edmonds who missed the extra assumption that the action has to be orientation-preserving for this to be true. As I said, this is a standard fact that if $M$ is a connected non-orientable manifold then the top-dimensional rational cohomology group vanishes (this should be in Hatcher's book). For surfaces, you can prove this by hand by computing the Euler characteristic or by working with the Mayer-Vietoris sequence.